# pi camera: The camera is already using port 0

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

**see below, for improved explanation of my problem**

I programmed a simple linefollower using OpenCV 4.1.2 on my Raspberry Pi. Everything worked just fine, but now I want to call a function which uses the camera.capture_continous function too. When I call the function (which should by the way detects circles in the camera frame) it only shoots one picture, detects some circles and then freezes and don't take any other pics. Here is a part of my source code:

```
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(320, 180))
rawCaptureCircles = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(320, 180))


for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):  
    counter = counter + 1

    image = frame.array
    line = cv2.inRange(image, (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 75)) 

    if counter > 10: #call function
        function()

    rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

and the function:

```
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):  
        imageCirles = frame.array
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(imageCirles, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # detect circles in the image
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 400)

        # ensure at least some circles were found
        if circles is not None:

            # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
            circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

            # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
            for (x, y, r) in circles:
                # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
                cv2.circle(imageCirles, (x, y), r, (255, 255, 0), 4)
                cv2.rectangle(imageCirles, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 0, 255), -1)

                cv2.putText(imageCirles, str(((x - 160) / 10) - 24), (100, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 0), 2)
```

I hope everything is more or less clear now.

**Edit:**

Here is a hopefully better explanation of my problem:

I'm desperate! I've tried (at least in my opinion) everything possible, but the function still doesn't work. But if I put the source code of the function into a separate python file and execute it, everything works fine! I know what the bug is in theory, but I really have no idea how to fix it. Here is another explanation of the problem:

The function named function() basically works perfectly (if I put it into an empty python and execute it), but every time I execute function() in my normal program, I get the following error message The camera is already using port 0.
This is because in my normal loop from the program

`for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True)`

use to create an endless loop But if function() is called now, the first line

`for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):`.

This causes me to get the error message mentioned above. Do I have to close the camera port before I can use it again?

Thanks for your answers

complete error message:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1663, in capture_continuous
    camera_port, output_port = self._get_ports(use_video_port, splitter_port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 562, in _get_ports
    'The camera is already using port %d ' % splitter_port)
picamera.exc.PiCameraAlreadyRecording: The camera is already using port 0 `
```

Comment: use `print()` in different places to see which part is executed. As for me second `capture_continuous` may run all time and it never ends `for`-loop. Maybe inside `function` you should use image which you get with first `capture_continuous` - this way function will run only once. And it will use only one `capture_continuous`

Comment: @furas I've already used print() in different places and it looks like the for(x, y, r) loop never get called. By the way the rescue function should be a loop, so after calling the function it should never stop detecting circles in the camera frame. Any ideas why it don't come to the for (x, y, r) loop or why the raspberry pi only shoots on picture?

Comment: if `for x, y, r in circle:`  is never called then use `print()` to see what you have in `circle`. And next use `print()` to check line which creates `circles = ... `, etc. And this way step by step move back and check every variable until you find place in which have diferent value then you expected. It is called "print debuging". And it is only way to answer for question why it doesn't work. It can't be resolver without running code and checking values in variables.

Comment: @furas I added a better explanation now. Maybe you know how to fix my error???

Comment: error means that camera is already used so you can't use it again with different function. And it can means you should use only one `capture_continuous()` and inside `function()` you should rather used image which you get with first `capture_continuous` - i.e. `function(frame)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want to do but your mistake is that you use second `capture_continuous`. You should use only one `capture_continuous` and send `frame` (or even `image`) as argument to `function(frame)` and it should use only this `frame`. And after processing this single frame it will go back to main loop which will run `function(frame)` again with next `frame` - so it will run like in `capture_continuous`

```
# --- functions ---

def function(frame):
    
    imageCirles = frame.array
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(imageCirles, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # detect circles in the image
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 400)

    # ensure at least some circles were found
    if circles is not None:

        # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

        # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
            cv2.circle(imageCirles, (x, y), r, (255, 255, 0), 4)
            cv2.rectangle(imageCirles, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 0, 255), -1)

            cv2.putText(imageCirles, str(((x - 160) / 10) - 24), (100, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 0), 2)

# --- main ---

rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(320, 180))

counter = 0

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):  
    counter += 1

    image = frame.array
    line = cv2.inRange(image, (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 75)) 

    if counter > 10: #call function
        function(frame)
        
    rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Eventually you can use `break` to exit one loop and then run other loop.

```
counter = 0

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):  
    counter += 1

    image = frame.array
    line = cv2.inRange(image, (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 75)) 

    if counter > 10: #call function
        break
        
    rawCapture.truncate(0)
    
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):  

    function(frame)
        
    rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

I'm not sure but it may gives small delay.

If first loop was used to follow line then it will not follow any more. Now it will check only circles. If you want follow line and check circles at the same time then you should run all in one `capture_continuous` as in first example.

Comment: Thank you man, I willl definitelly try this suggestion

Comment: There is still one problem: Actually the Raspberry Pi should repeat the function() infinitely as soon as the variable counter > 10. But with your program suggestion this would not work. Wouldn't it??? I know that this idea is not perfect, but what's about closing the main python file and automatically execute a new one called "function.py" instead of calling the function function() in my normal program. Wouldn't that also get rid of the error?

Comment: this code should repeate `function()` infinity (and code which is inside function) becaues it is executed in `for`-loop. Did you test it? BTW: if you want some code execute only when `counter < 10` then you can use `if/else` - `if counter > 10: function(frame) else: other_function()`

Comment: Other method is to exit current loop using `break` - `if counter > 10: break`  - and then you can start new `for`-loop - but it may need to close and reopen camera so it may give delay. And it doesn't need to run code from other file.

Comment: Yes I tested it, but your suggestions should solve my problems. I close the camera with the close() function, right?